# adding event listener to the html drawing

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have made this drawing in html. I am trying to add an event listener that when a user clicks the drawing will start to display from top to bottom.

```js
var valueTemplate = [
  'repeating-linear-gradient(00deg',
  ' #FFFFFF 0px',
  ' transparent 1px',
  ' transparent 5px',
  ' #FFFFFF 6px)'
].join(',');

var lineVariants = [
  ['vertical', 90, 'FFFF00'],
  ['horizontal', 0, '00FF00'],
  ['diagonal-left', 45, '0000FF'],
  ['diagonal-right', 135, 'FF0000']
];

var mappings = [
  [[0], [1], [2], [3]],
  [[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [3, 2]],
  [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
  [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
];
    
var css = '';
var property = 'background-image';
var index;
var selector;
var value;

for (var s = 0; s < mappings.length; s++) {
  for (var o = 0; o < mappings[s].length; o++) {
    selector = [];
    value = [];
    for (var l = 0; l < mappings[s][o].length; l++) {
      index = mappings[s][o][l];
      selector.push(lineVariants[index][0]);
      value.push(
        valueTemplate
        .replace(/([0]{2})/, lineVariants[index][1])
        .replace(/[F]{6}/g, lineVariants[index][2])
      );
    }
    selector = '.' + selector.join('-');
    value = property + ':' + value.join(',');
    css += [selector, value].join('{') + '}';
  }
}
var styleNode = document.createElement('style');
styleNode.innerText = css;
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(styleNode);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.number85 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sol {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}

.lewitt {
  width: calc(100% / 6);
}

.wall {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}

.drawing {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="number85">
  <div class="sol vertical"></div>
  <div class="sol horizontal"></div>
  <div class="sol diagonal-right"></div>
  <div class="sol diagonal-left"></div>

  <div class="lewitt vertical-horizontal"></div>
  <div class="lewitt vertical-diagonal-right"></div>
  <div class="lewitt vertical-diagonal-left"></div>
  <div class="lewitt horizontal-diagonal-right"></div>
  <div class="lewitt horizontal-diagonal-left"></div>
  <div class="lewitt diagonal-right-diagonal-left"></div>

  <div class="wall vertical-horizontal-diagonal-right"></div>
  <div class="wall vertical-horizontal-diagonal-left"></div>
  <div class="wall vertical-diagonal-left-diagonal-right"></div>
  <div class="wall horizontal-diagonal-left-diagonal-right"></div>

  <div class="drawing vertical-horizontal-diagonal-left-diagonal-right"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: `calc(100% / 4)`is and always will be `25%` :) Anyway, what have you tried? There's no jQuery in your question or code, so I've removed the tag for now.

Comment: Also it is not clear what you want the drawing to do. Redraw? `document.querySelector("number85").addEventListener("click",function() { your loop function });`

Comment: @mplungjan yes i want to do the  drawing to redraw when a user clicks on the screen .
how should i add this line above in my code , can you specify a bit more please

Comment: what loop function are you referring to?

Comment: @ChrisG i want to add a jquery that will allow me when a user clicks on the screen the drawing wil draw from top-to-bottom .
is it possible beacuse i am stuck in how to implement it ?